# Reading csv with Laravel excel not working

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5.1

I'm trying dd() output of a csv file, but I just get blank page.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Excel;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function test()
    {
        $file = Excel::load('public/hot.csv')->toArray();
        dd($file);
    }

}
```

I can see its loading the file because file is pretty big and I can see progress bar is taking while to load file when I visit the url that hits test() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to use `Excel::load`.

```
Excel::load('public/hot.csv', function($reader) {
    $results = $reader->get();
    dd($results->toArray());
});
```

Comment: I was able to do it both ways, but turns out the problem was that file was too big, it worked with smaller file, but with bigger file I used chunk() in their documentation, it reads about quarter of the file and throws execution timeout error, is there any way around it without raising that limit ?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way except increasing the time limit. However you can use `set_time_limit ( time )` in the controller's constructor to increase execution time of that specific controller.